# Proxy to express - 500-timeout - Server code is executed more then once

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy

I don't know what is going on. When i try to send request to the backend to add follower(my route bellow), I get server tiemout error instead of sucess, but in my database the follower is added correctly(and removed), buuuut not always. Sometimes it saves 3 times the same result(follower to db), or sometimes doesn't delete the follower.
And the problem is that i have no idea what's is going on.

In my console i have this error sometimes i see this:
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/users/user/follow from 127.0.0.1:8080 to http://[::1]:1648 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

setFollower route:

```js
const setFollowing = async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
      const userId = req.body.userId;
      const followId = req.body.followId;
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
         userId,
         {
            $push: {
               following: followId,
            },
         },
      );
      next();
   } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
         error: err,
      });
   }
};

const setFollower = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   try {
      const followId = req.body.followId;
      const userId = req.body.userId;
      const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
         followId,
         {
            $push: {
               followers: userId,
            },
         },
         { new: true },
      )
         .populate('following', '_id name')
         .populate('followers', '_id name')

      const followerResult = { ...result._doc };
      const { photo, salt, passwordHash, ...rest } = followerResult;

      return res.status({ ...rest });

   } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
         error: err,
      });
   }
};


router.put(
   '/user/follow',
   isUserSignIn,
   setFollowing,
   setFollower,
);
```

sending request on button click

```js
   try {
         setLoading(true);
         const response = await fetch('/api/users/user/follow', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
               followId: params.userId,
               userId: loggedInUser._id,
            }),
            headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'PUT',
         });
         const data = await response.json();


         setLoading(false);
         setFollowing(true);
      } catch (err) {
         if (err.message) {
            setServerError(err.message);
         } else {
            setServerError(JSON.stringify(err));
         }
      }
```

my repo: https://github.com/bartek-fecko/fullstackapp

Answer (score 0):

for my assumption, you're using express, given the logs you have in your question. The 
   key is to set the timeout property on server (the following sets the timeout to one 
   second, use whatever value you want):

```
  var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
       debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
        });
       server.timeout = 1000;
```

Comment: what? idk what you say